# How to scrape WSJ headlines with requests and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

WSJ doesn't want to be parsed - I have this function:

```
def get_wsj_news():
    global prev_news_wsj
    url = "https://www.wsj.com/news/world"
    news = []
    news_to_post = []
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        news_list = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "WSJTheme--headline--unZqjb45"})
        for item in news_list[:15]:
            headline = item.text.strip()
            news.append(f"• {headline}")
            news_to_post.append(f"• <b>{headline}</b>")
        if not news or news == prev_news_wsj:
            return {"site": None, "message": None}
        else:
            prev_news_wsj = news
            print(url)
            return {"site": "The Wall Street Journal", "message": "\n".join(news_to_post)}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

but when I'm trying to parse `<h3>` tags I see this:

> We can’t find the page you're looking for. If you typed the URL into your browser, check that you entered it correctly. If you reached this page via our site or search, please let us know by emailing support@wsj.com

Answer (score 1):

*WSJ will have its reasons, which should be respected - the pages are made for humans, not bots, so if you behave like a human, the content is open to you.*

---

In this case, it is already sufficient to work with a [`user agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) in the request, but *this could change, if they will detect your activities and classify them as inadmissible*.

Therefore, treat the site and its content once again with respect, and do not harm it through rash actions and unnecessary scraping.

###### Example

*This is only to show the technical point of view and does not reflect the ethical one.*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.wsj.com/news/world"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'some agent'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "WSJTheme--headline--unZqjb45"})
```